# I'm not sure what is happening. Are my routes going crazy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

These are part of my routes.

```
   activity_groups GET    /activity_groups(.:format)                                activity_groups#index
                           POST   /activity_groups(.:format)                                activity_groups#create
        new_activity_group GET    /activity_groups/new(.:format)                            activity_groups#new
       edit_activity_group GET    /activity_groups/:id/edit(.:format)                       activity_groups#edit
            activity_group GET    /activity_groups/:id(.:format)                            activity_groups#show
                           PUT    /activity_groups/:id(.:format)                            activity_groups#update
                           DELETE /activity_groups/:id(.:format)                            activity_groups#destroy
                      root        /                                                         main#index
```

Minimal view:

**activity_groups/show**

```
%h2 Activity Ggroup

%h3= @activity_group.title

= link_to "Edit", edit_activity_group_path(@activity_group)
|
= link_to "Delete", activity_group_path(@activity_group), {confirm: (I18n.t "confirmations.activity_group.delete"), method: :delete}
|
= link_to "Back", activity_groups_path
```

The index is a little bit more complex:

**activity_groups/index**

```
.row
    .span8
        %h1.padding_bottom1 Activity Groups

        - if !@activity_groups.empty?

            %ul.span6
                %li.span1 F
                %li.span2 Name
                %li.span2 Actions

            = render @activity_groups
            = render @activities
        - else
            %h2.extra_padding You have no Activity Groups yet. Add one and start managing your time. 

    .span6.padding_top1
        =link_to "Create Activity Group", new_activity_group_path, {class: 'btn'}
        =link_to "Create Activity", new_activity_path, {class: 'btn'}
```

**activity_groups/_activity_group.html.haml**

```
%ul.span6
    %li.span1
        %i.icon-folder-close.folder
    %li.span2
        = activity_group.title
    %li.span2
        PROBLEM

    - if !activity_group.activity_groups.empty?
        - activity_group.activity_groups.each do |activity_group|
            = render partial: 'activity_group', locals: {activity_group: activity_group}

    - if !activity_group.activities.empty?
        - activity_group.activities.each do |activity|
            = render partial: 'activities/activity', locals: {activity: activity}
```

**PROBLEM** If i place a `link_to "Show", activity_groups_path(activity_group)` here my routes go crazy. My activity_groups_path is gone. I can't access it anymore. It tries to redirect me to the show view and not to the index view. I really don't understand why this happens. Any ideas?

**[EDIT1]**

I started with a clean database. If I try to place a link for the show page now I get a NameError `undefined local variable or method`activity_group_path'`

**[EDIT2]** corrected misspell above

Comment: `activiy_group_path` <- this typo isn't in your code is it?

Comment: undefined local variable or method activiy_group_path'` ... activity is misspelled. Not sure if that's the issue

Comment: @NickColgan I don't have that typo in my code. I just misspelled on SO out of frustration.

Comment: @iouri I don't have that typo in my code.

Comment: are you rendering partial from within itself? render partial: 'activity_group', locals: {activity_group: activity_group} inside of activity_group partial?

Comment: @iouri I have a model Activity_group that has_many :activity_groups. I am rendering the partial within itself until all activity groups are rendered. That part works...

Comment: Just for kicks, if you use link_to "show", activity_group_path(ActivityGroup.first) does it work then?

Comment: @iouri hmm... It does...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you passing object to your link path?

```
activity_group_path(@activity_group)
```

Comment: I am passing a parameter. In this case activity_group without @

Comment: I think I had a typo somewhere that I just didn't see I replaced ActivityGroup.first with activity_group and it works now. I spent half an hour on this and I didn't see it... thanks...

Answer (score 1):

you mentioned you used `activity_groups_path(activity_group)` above - this should be `activity_group_path(activity_group)` (group not groups). May be /an/ issue but maybe not the only one. (maybe not the only one, sounds like your recursive call of the same partial and passing the child activity_groups as :local may eventually call the route with an invalid activity group object. Just a hunch)

As an aside I have spent many similar frustrated hours with Rails routes and it always comes down to something stupid I did (though the syntax is to blame as well, it's just a bad approximation of english). Take a break, get something to eat, take a nap... may be obvious then.